# Why makes storing a reference instead of requesting it twice my application so much slower?

Tags: c++

An object `memory` has a method with the signature

```
BinaryPattern const& getPattern(unsigned int index) const;
```

I'm using this in the following for-loop:

```
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < memory->size(); k++) {
    const BinaryPattern s = memory->getPattern(k);
    w += s.at(i) * s.at(j);
}
```

This is very slow. Surprisingly, I found that the following is much faster:

```
for (unsigned int k = 0; k < memory->size(); k++) {
    w += memory->getPattern(k).at(i) * memory->getPattern(k).at(j);
}
```

"getPattern()" does not do any computations, it pretty much just returns the pattern that is stored in a vector.

Why is it so much slower when I store the reference in a variable? I initially did this to speed things up, as I expected retrieving the reference twice to be slower.

Comment: Change it to `const BinaryPattern &s = memory->getPattern(k);`

Comment: @sbi: I was wrong about the specific details (I don't know much about C++). I was referring to copy constructor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor , which you have explained in your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because

```
const BinaryPattern s = memory->getPattern(k);
```

makes a copy of the object by calling its copy constructor. Since you don't want to change it, store a reference instead:

```
const BinaryPattern& s = memory->getPattern(k);
//                 ^
//                 note this
```

(Since capturing an rvalue with a `const` reference extends the rvalue's lifetime until the reference dies, this even works should the signature of `getPattern()` ever be changed to return a copy, rather than a reference.)

---

In an optimized build (you didn't compare debug builds, did you?), the compiler might be able to determine that the two calls to the function in

```
memory->getPattern(k).at(i) * memory->getPattern(k).at(j)
```

don't have any side effects and is thus keeping the reference to the object obtained by the first call and optimizing away the second call — arriving at the code I proposed above.

Obviously, the cost of copying a `BinaryPattern` object is not neglectable.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I always thought that returning a const-reference would be sufficient to make the variable a reference rather than a copy.

Comment: @Niko: The variable `s` in your code is an object, not a reference. What it is initialized from has no influence over that.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are creating a copy here

```
const BinaryPattern s = memory->getPattern(k);
```

Just change to

```
const BinaryPattern &s = memory->getPattern(k);
```

Comment: `+1` because you are correct — although a few seconds late. `:)`

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
const BinaryPattern s = memory->getPattern(k);
```

an new instance of `BinaryPattern` is created and the return value of `getPattern` is copied into it.

You probably meant

```
const BinaryPattern& s = memory->getPattern(k);
```

Comment: `+1` because you are correct — although a few seconds late. `:)`